# typescript callback parameter type by callback arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

```
function funcOne<T extends boolean = false>(isTrue: T) {
  type RETURN = T extends true ? string : number;
  return (isTrue ? "Cool" : 10) as RETURN;
}

function funcCb<T>(cb: (isTrue: boolean) => T) {
  const getFirst = () => cb(true);
  const getSecond = () => cb(false);

  return {
    getFirst,
    getSecond
  };
}

const result = funcCb((isTrueInCb) => {
  return funcOne(isTrueInCb);
});
```

funcCb return type,  which I get

```
  const result: {
    getFirst: () => string | number;
    getSecond: () => string | number;
}
```

But how can I achieve this

```
 const result: {
    getFirst: () => string;
    getSecond: () => number;
}
```

I don't want to use `as` like   `const getFirst = () => cb(true) as string;`.

I want to it automatically infer the type based on `funcCb` argument value. `funcCb` may be used with other functions like

```
function funcTwo<T extends boolean = false>(isTrue: T) {
  type RETURN = T extends true ? Date : string;
  return (isTrue ? new Date() : new Date().toString()) as RETURN;
}
```

Comment: ehy! did you check my response? =)

Comment: Hmm, TS isn't a dependently-typed language, nor does it have true higher kinded types, so some of the inference you're expecting here is just not possible.  You can get close-ish to what you want as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NDeyzm) but it requires manual specification of type arguments (which the compiler *checks* for you, but it doesn't *infer* them).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up a full answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this and it seems to be working =)

```
function funcOne<T extends boolean = false>(isTrue: T) {
  type RETURN = T extends true ? string : number;
  return (isTrue ? "Cool" : 10) as RETURN;
}

function funcCb<T>(cb: (isTrueInCb: false) => number): { getString: string, getNumber: number } 
function funcCb<T>(cb: (isTrueInCb: true) => string): { getString: string, getNumber: number } 
function funcCb<T>(cb: (isTrueInCb: any) => T): { getString: T, getNumber: T } {
  const getString = cb(true);
  const getNumber = cb(false);

  return {
    getString,
    getNumber
  };
}

const result = funcCb((isTrueInCb) => {
  return funcOne(isTrueInCb);
});
```

here a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSB5MBTAPAFURgDygzABMBnRAIzjgBsMBDJAXmUbvIwD4AKGcjgBOIDAC5EOAJSIA3gFgAUIkRQAngAcMiAEoBRHAFUdAOURs8hYmUpQR2gPyJydmGADmiCWBABbKhhCANxKKkIYUCBCSPyC9ohOAEQAwrR0iV6IAIwADDKMlPpGpiGKAL5KSijQ8EjVyVS4fBBUErHCogCSYA0SwBxcMizciD7%20gVISsojuEQDKrh4SLkJu7gA0MxEmfgFC3ruBiGWIVeA1CMjnDU28LW0CHRjdvar2QyMra5NyW1ALqyWzkWGz%20O3G%201GhyEx1OimqsEu9UaOGarUQ7XsL3RzDUH0kP2ms3%20IIkOE2xPBezJsIUykQEAQLj%20ALW5gZVF4dlEUlKKkZYGZlOh7JavH6nAwvMq9PCkWiclCKhZIPWSpUwohSrKpQqiiUAuZ4XIIDoUHZyN4mK6PSo%20LpYQiUTq53QGGtz1t0vKvKAA) on TS site:

Comment: did you try it? does it work =)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It works but I don't want to explicitly set the type of `getString`. I want to it automatically infer the type based on `funcCb` arguments. funcCb maybe use with other function like `funcTwo<T extends boolean = false>(isTrue: T): T extends true ? Date : string`;

Comment: I think i found a way ..
shall I edit my previous answer?

Comment: check it here, [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=33&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBASgogFQKowHIB4ED4oF4oJQQAewEAdgCYDOUwATgK7QD8U1DAluQOZQBcUcowC2AIwj0A3AFgAUPIBmjcgGNgnAPbkoytQHlyETEVIUaUMZs0AbCAEMd+RfZvUIWABSdqCJhEEEAEooAG95KCh6CGBGeh1vX38oNgAiAGFrG1SBKABGAAYQ+1p4ZDRMLFk5AF95JRV1LR09VXSxT1UxQVVXGzF7VQBrEPC5SNVtDigeGIAxTnpp-E8Q3BwuzwZmIOqJqeAZmIBlCEmqPChVvA2OlzcIXfrxqJi4nTHIyNngBaXgAA0ES+P1O50owJq1TqCjk3DI9BcqmgvRs-UGQzCwJMJDIVFoVlsDnIXh8fmYAElyO1+MF+GUUBhsPIYedpqj0cN+ByBsNLolyRAqe01jhPq9YvFdI1DBABf5hWInrVnmzDtFqIwbIdnI12p0+ryRlIgA)

Comment: I simply took you RETURN definition out from the scope of the function and I made it be generic, then I defined the interface for the callback an pass the interface to the definition of the funcCb

Comment: @VishalMishra di you check what I suggested? what do you think about it?